# My theme saves their custom post type's metadata as a serialized array, how to access the keys?

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta, array

I've recently bought the WP Directory Portal theme from ThemeForest.
Since the theme doesn't do frontend posting of custom post types, I've resulted to using WP User Frontend Pro.

There's a problem hooking into the custom post type meta though.

When I check PHPmyAdmin, I find the following field: _ait-dir-item in wp_postmeta

With the content:

```
a:19:{s:7:”address”;s:17:”Street”;s:11:”gpsLatitude”;s:17:”12.341251949999999″;s:12:”

gpsLongitude”;s:17:”12.34779700000025″;s:18:”streetViewLatitude”;s:17:”22.46046022895586″;

s:19:”streetViewLongitude”;s:17:”22.006520910937523″;s:17:”streetViewHeading”;

s:1:”0″;s:15:”streetViewPitch”;s:1:”0″;s:14:”streetViewZoom”;s:1:”0″;s:9:”telephone”;s:0:””;

s:5:”email”;s:17:”tester@retroga.me”;s:3:”web”;s:0:””;s:11:”hoursMonday”;s:0:””;s:12:”hoursTuesday”;s:0

:””;s:14:”hoursWednesday”;s:0:””;s:13:”hoursThursday”;s:0:””;s:11:”hoursFriday”;s:0:””;s:13:”hoursSaturday

“;s:0:””;s:11:”hoursSunday”;s:0:””;s:18:”alternativeContent”;s:4:”Test”;}
```

I was wondering how I could access those variables, so that I can make this work with the theme's custom post type.

I've tried both support forums, and the WP User Frontend author's been helping out a bit, but I could use some further insight into this.

If anyone is willing to help me out with this, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just wondering if you found a solution for this. I have a similar question here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/159385/how-can-i-programmatically-save-data-into-custom-fields-that-contain-serialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That data is serialised PHP, if you pass in a PHP structure it will be serialised into a string. When you pull it back out, it's de-serialised automatically, e.g.:

```
$post_id = current post ID.....
$data = get_post_meta( $post_id, '', true );
```

To see the structure in a human readable form, use something like this:

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r( $data, true ).'</pre>';
```

For information about how you would access the information stored in this `$data` variable, please refer to php.net for basic array and object access `[]` and `->`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Excuse me for not understanding exactly. The plugin I'm using basically provides input fields that can be linked to meta keys. Since the data is in an array, I'm wondering how I could get that input stored in that array under those keys. All the plugin asks for is the meta key. Should I write a function that would translate a different (self-made) metakey to be serialized in that array using the code you typed above?

Comment: I'm completely, and utterly unfamiliar with the WP User Frontend plugin, I recommend you abandon these plugins as they fall apart quickly once you move beyond their basic functionality. It is likely more work to make the plugin do what you want then it would be to just implement everything yourself

Comment: Well, since I paid for them, I'd rather use em to the fullest. The thing is that I'm currently refactoring myself from an iPad Developer to a Web Developer so in time, there'll be knowledge on how to do all this. The problem is just that I'm impatient and don't want my site to sit there doing nothing (since it's based on that functionality, for which I thought the plugin and the theme would be a means to an end).

Comment: hmmm those plugins tend to be all in one solutions, they dont account for data that might be stored in an unexpected format, but the docs may point out some ways fo extending it, outside of the plugin support you're not going to find many people familiar with it

Comment: I'll have a look-see. Thanks for the help so far! I'll close this question :).

Comment: This part of the docs may help you: http://docs.wedevs.com/wp-user-frontend-pro/#plugin-integration But beyond that I can't really advise, access the post meta is easy, and what you originally asked for, but integrating the two plugins together is a whole new problem and one that I'm unprepared for

Comment: No problem Tom, your help is greatly appreciated! 
Apparently the theme is using the Nette/Latte framework to generate those things. I'm currently asking the theme devs if they can't save their metadata in separate keys, or know a way how to. That way I can just use the WP User Frontend Pro plugin to save to those keys.