# How can I programmatically save data into custom fields that contain serialized data?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, wp-insert-post

I purchased a theme from themeforest recently that has a custom post type.  Here is a link to a page that's been created with the custom post type:

http://bluepresley.com/farmerfinder/?dir-item=dance-relax

The custom post type has approximately 20 different custom fields, but you can see from my array dump that the one one field has been saved as serialized data:

(array dump using get_post_custom())

```
Array
(
    [_edit_last] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [_ait-dir-item] => Array
        (
            [0] => a:20:{s:7:"address";s:51:"276 Canal Street, New York, NY 10013, United States";s:11:"gpsLatitude";s:17:"40.71958306715651";s:12:"gpsLongitude";s:17:"-74.0379810333252";s:14:"showStreetview";a:1:{s:6:"enable";s:6:"enable";}s:18:"streetViewLatitude";s:9:"40.719679";s:19:"streetViewLongitude";s:18:"-74.03797400000002";s:17:"streetViewHeading";s:18:"-151.8987176681924";s:15:"streetViewPitch";s:17:"5.196265482127373";s:14:"streetViewZoom";s:1:"0";s:9:"telephone";s:13:"044 802 52578";s:5:"email";s:19:"directory@email.com";s:3:"web";s:17:"www.aitthemes.com";s:11:"hoursMonday";s:9:"8am - 8pm";s:12:"hoursTuesday";s:9:"8am - 8pm";s:14:"hoursWednesday";s:9:"8am - 8pm";s:13:"hoursThursday";s:9:"8am - 8pm";s:11:"hoursFriday";s:9:"8am - 8pm";s:13:"hoursSaturday";s:6:"closed";s:11:"hoursSunday";s:6:"closed";s:18:"alternativeContent";s:33:"What goes in alternative content?";}
        )

    [_thumbnail_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8159
        )

    [_edit_lock] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1409208357:1
        )

    [slide_template] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )
)
```

Please note the key in question is _ait-dir-item.

I noticed in the form itself all form fields were named `name="_ait-dir-item[address]"` (for example).

If this is the case, how do I programmatically add items? Is this typical Wordpress and there is a way to handle this approach? I assume I'm not going to be able to use `add_post_meta( $post_id, 'mymetakey', $my_long );`  or other approaches found [here](http://tommcfarlin.com/programmatically-create-a-post-in-wordpress/) and [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post). ?

Answer (score 2):

For serializing and unserializing Data in Wordpress, you can use [maybe_unserialize](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_unserialize) and [maybe_serialize](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_serialize). If you want to handle the data and add/change values, you could use something like this:

```
$metaarray = maybe_unserialize(get_post_meta($post_id,'_ait-dir-item',TRUE));
//now $metaarray has an array, if it is serialized. If not, $metaarray has a string.
if(is_array($metaarray)){
     $metaarray['mynewfield'] = 'Some text i need to add';
     $metaarray['mysecondnewfield'] = array('an' => 'array','i' => 'need', 'to' => 'add');
}
update_post_meta($post_id,'_ait-dir-item',maybe_serialize($metaarray));
```

Happy Coding,
Kuchenundkakao